# Normalizr - How to handle nested entities that are already normalized

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

I have entities in very nested JSON that already follow the normalizr format where the idAttribute is already the key where the object is defined:

```
groups: [{
  id: 'foo',
  families: {
    smiths: {
      people: [{
        id: 'sam',
      }, {
        id: 'jake',
      }],
    },
    jones: {
      people: [{
        id: 'john',
      }, {
        id: 'sue',
      }],
    },
  },
}];
```

In this example, notice that the `families` attribute is using the id (`smiths`, `jones`) to identify the `people` who are an array of objects with ids.

The schemas for this might look like:

```
const person = new Entity('person');
const family = new Entity('family', {
  people: [person],
}, {idAttribute: ???});
const group = new Entity('family', {
  family: [family],
});
```

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to specify that a schema's idAttribute is the key where it is defined? In other words, how would I define the schema for `Family` as it's related to `groups` and `people`?

Another question, is there a way to `denormalize` a flattened state so that the families `families: {[id]: obj}` pattern stays the same as it is in the example json above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify that a schema's idAttribute is the key where it is defined?

Yes. The `idAttribute` function takes 3 arguments: `value`, `parent`, and `key`. Please read the [docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#entitykey-definition---options--). In your case, you can use the `key`, along with `schema.Values`

```
const family = new schema.Entity('families', { 
    people: [ person ] 
}, (value, parent, key) => key);
const families = new schema.Values(family);
const group = new schema.Entity('groups', {
    families
});
```

For `denormalize`, you'll need a separate schema for `family`, since the ID can't be derived from the key.

Comment: This returns `families` as the key, not the `smiths` or `jones` values I am after

Comment: Sorry, misread and forgot you need to use `schema.Values` on that object of families

Comment: Is there any way to not return families as an object? Currently getting 
` families: { smiths: 'smiths', jones: 'jones' } ` which is something we can work with but would be nice if families was returned as an array instead: 
` families: [ 'smiths', 'jones' ] `